# AWS EC2 Instance w/ WordPress keeps crashing from 25% CPU utilization spikes

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 t2.medium instance i-0bf4623a779064e0a with a WordPress installation which keeps crashing (can't be accessed via http or SSH). It seems whenever CPU utilization gets to about 25% or more (which I would think isn't very much), the server crashes. I have an alert setup to restart the server whenever Network Out is <=50,000 bytes for 5 minutes and tonight it's had to restart 10 times. It has been doing this nearly everyday for weeks. Here is a screenshot of the monitoring https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB5XO.png

What can I do to stop this crashing? Can I do some sort of server config optimization? I hope I do not need a larger instance, since I am already paying quite a bit for AWS and previously using a $10/mo shared hosting which rarely went down.

Comment: If you can access the instance, check for memory utilization stats and look at your DB status (Memory, CPU, process list). It might the case where the db is reaching its capacity.

Comment: just remove this alert setup.. I think that is causing the problem

Comment: In a t2.medium wordpress should work and did you tried AWS Lightsail to host Wordpress? which comes with prebuilt templates like other hosting providers

Comment: Hi, Have you checked balance CPU credit?. once you restart instance you will get one hour of CPU credit. you can use two spot instance other then t2(like M series ) in auto-scaling that's will cost same.

Comment: I had this issue and it turned out I was nearly out of disk space. SSH in and df -h

Comment: increasing volume from 8GB to 25GB (which is allowed under free tier) solved my issue